# Appcelerator Titanium Alloy model save does not persist when custom id specified in the adapter

Tags: model, save, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I have an [Alloy](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Quick_Start) [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org) model defined like the following:

```
exports.definition = {
config: {
    columns: {
        "RequestCode" : "INTEGER",
        "Type" : "text",
        "Title": "text",
    },

    adapter: {
        type: "sql",
        collection_name: "EventDAO",
        idAttribute: "RequestCode"
    }
},

extendModel: function(Model) {
    _.extend(Model.prototype, {
        // extended functions and properties go here
        }
    });

    return Model;
},

extendCollection: function(Collection) {
    _.extend(Collection.prototype, {
        // extended functions and properties go here
    });

    return Collection;
}
};
```

The problem is when i try to update a model of the collection. The updates are not persisted. I use the following code to retrieve and update a model:

```
var collection = Alloy.createCollection("EventDAO");
collection.fetch();

var first_model = collection.at(0);

first_model.set({
  Title: "Modified title"
});

first_model.save();
```

Next time when i try to retrieve the same model the Title attribute is not changed.
This doesn't happen if i remove the line

```
idAttribute: "RequestCode"
```

in the adapter definition of the model.

Is this a bug or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

When you're debugging Alloy collection issues, it's worth taking a look into the sqlite database.

The file will be here on iOS simulator (default db name) :
`~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/SIMULATORUID/data/Containers/Data/Application/APPID/Library/Private Documents/_alloy_.sql`

Use something like http://sqlitebrowser.org/ to browse the Table, refresh to see app updates.